# Port not opened in azure, how to fix that?

Tags: ubuntu, azure, django

I am running django project on a azure ubuntu 18 machine.
It runs on 8000 port. So I opened the port from security section of azure.

[image: port opened]

And the firewall is inactive on that machine.

[image: firewall status]

But still, I can't access the 8000 port.

[image: web access]

How to fix that?

Comment: Are you sure that django is up and running? Did you try to run netstat -atunp? Also you can double check if you have NSG linked to neither NIC or VNET. There is a resource called [Network Watcher](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/diagnose-vm-network-traffic-filtering-problem) where you can make sure that everything is ok for NSG and network.

Comment: I think you have to associate your network security group with a subnet or a specific network interface.

Comment: @asmath, it is created by default with the VM. So all the associations could be made already. And SSH rule is already working.